# How to remove a widget in PYQT6 after it was added using a CheckBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt6

I am developing a Python GUI using PYQT6. The code below is a reduced version of my code that illustrates my problem. When the GUI comes up first time, I want to show an unchecked CheckBox widget, and below it a DateEdit widget. In addition, when I check the CheckBox, a LineEdit widget is added to the left of the DateEdit widget. So far the software works fine. However, when I uncheck the CheckBox to remove the LineEdit widget from the layout, the LineEdit widget continues to show in the layout. Any help is appreciated.

```
import  sys
from    PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QCheckBox,
        QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QDateEdit, QLineEdit )
from    PyQt6 import QtCore
from    PyQt6.QtCore import QDate

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")
        global layout3 

        layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout3 = QHBoxLayout()

        # Define the QCheckBox widget.
        self.CheckBox = QCheckBox("Enable Sales", self)
        self.CheckBox.toggled.connect(self.checkbox_toggled)
        
        # Define the QLineEdit widget
        self.item_entry = QLineEdit()
        self.item_entry.setPlaceholderText("Enter item")

        # Define the QDateEdit widget and set its date to the current date.
        self.date_entry = QDateEdit()
        self.date_entry.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.date_entry.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.date_entry.setEnabled(True)
        current_dated = QDate.currentDate()
        self.date_entry.setDate(current_dated)

        # Outline the layouts and add to them the CheckBox and the DateEdit widgets.
        # The QLineEdit widget will be added later dynamically.                                                
        layout1.addLayout(layout2)      
        layout2.addWidget(self.CheckBox, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        layout2.addLayout(layout3)         
        layout3.addWidget(self.date_entry)
                 
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout1)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)       
    
    def checkbox_toggled(self):
        if self.CheckBox.isChecked() == True:
            layout3.addWidget(self.item_entry)   
            layout3.addWidget(self.date_entry)
        else:
            layout3.removeWidget(self.item_entry)
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Did you consider to just *hide* the widget instead of removing it from the layout? In this way you could even show it again if you need it later. Besides, as the documentation explains, [`removeWidget()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#removeWidget) "Removes the widget from the layout. After this call, it is the caller's responsibility to give the widget a reasonable geometry or to put the widget back into a layout or to explicitly hide it if necessary. Note: The ownership of widget remains the same as when it was added."

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. My example is a reduced version of my real GUI layout. By hiding the widget, the other widgets will stay at the same location as before. In my real case there are more horizontally-spaced widgets that must be in the center of the screen after the LineEdit is removed. Note that if I do not require to have the LineEdit and the DateEdit show up when the GUI starts, the current software  can add and remove the LineEdit widget each time I check and uncheck the box. I tried it. I do not understand why my code layout3.removeWidget(self.item_entry) does not work.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that properly represents your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this problem would be to delete the widget each time the checkbox becomes unchecked, and recreate it when it becomes checked.  THis will completely remove it and allow the DateEdit Widget to grow and be totally visible.

For example:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")
        layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout3 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.CheckBox = QCheckBox("Enable Sales", self)
        self.CheckBox.toggled.connect(self.checkbox_toggled)
        self.date_entry = QDateEdit()
        self.date_entry.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.date_entry.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.date_entry.setEnabled(True)
        current_dated = QDate.currentDate()
        self.date_entry.setDate(current_dated)
        layout1.addLayout(layout2)
        layout2.addWidget(self.CheckBox, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        layout2.addLayout(self.layout3)
        self.layout3.addWidget(self.date_entry)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout1)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def checkbox_toggled(self):
        if self.CheckBox.isChecked() == True:
            self.item_entry = QLineEdit()
            self.item_entry.setPlaceholderText("Enter item")
            self.layout3.addWidget(self.item_entry)
            self.layout3.addWidget(self.date_entry)
        else:
            i = self.layout3.indexOf(self.item_entry)
            self.layout3.takeAt(i)
            self.item_entry.deleteLater()
```

> P.S. I turned the layout3 into an instance attribute so that you could access it in the checkbutton slot method without needing to make it a global variable.  Changing it was for my own preference and it is not necessary for the solution to work.

Comment: Alexander, I checked it also without turning the layout into an instance attribute and as you said, it works too. Can you tell me why did you use the following statements:                                 ***i = self.layout3.indexOf(self.item_entry)
            self.layout3.takeAt(i) *** It  works also without these statement. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Menachem  No specific reason.  In my experience using the `takeAt` performs better than the `remove` method, but it might be my imagination

Comment: Actually the RemoveWidget method that I used doesn't work at all. Only your suggested deleteLater() method works. I do not understand  why. I notice that the deleteLater() method also works without the two statements that I mentioned above.

Comment: I am not certain about the why's but the `takeAt` does work at removing the widget from the layout.  But that isn't enough to completely remove the widget from the window all together, it just no longer bound to a layout.  the `deleteLater` is what destroys it entirely

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the differences. The good news is that PYQT6 helps in creating nice GUIs for Python projects. I am currently converting several of my command-line based Python projects to GUI-based projects. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Sure thing.  Don't forget to mark the question as answered...